# How to take price from customer and use taken price in cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, custom-options

I want to set up product in which some custom options. For this i have created custom options from product, but for price i want to take it from customer and use that price in cart.

Product like this
http://www.getrxd.com/gift-card.html

Please give some solution.

Comment: Pls use custom extension : https://magegiant.com/magento-gift-card/?gclid=CNP6s_KS8ckCFdWFaAod7ZUB4Q

Answer (score 0):

Use observer for this logic:

In your module **config.xml**

```
<events>
<sales_quote_add_item>
    <observers>
        <customer_price>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>OBSERVER_CLASS_NAME</class>
            <method>customerPrice</method>
        </customer_price>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

In method:

```
public function customerPrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $new_price = '10'; /*GET_CUSTOMER_PRICE_FROM SESSION*/
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```